# How to add a column to typed table without altering type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5, I have a TYPE which discribes a collection of columns:

```
CREATE TYPE datastore.record AS
   (recordid bigint,
    ...
    tags text[]);
```

I have created many tables reliying on this TYPE:

```
CREATE TABLE datastore.events
OF datastore.record;
```

Now I would like to add a column to a table which rely on this TYPE without updating the TYPE. I think it is impossible as this, thus I am wondering if there is a way to unbind my table from this TYPE without losing any data or copying the table into a temporary table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a special option `not of` for this purpose. Per [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertable.html):

> NOT OF - This form dissociates a typed table from its type.

So:

```
alter table my_table not of;
alter table my_table add new_column integer;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was not aware about the NOT OF Keyword. All my relation are preserved,

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know about the `not of`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to break relations:

```
--drop table if exists t2;
--drop table if exists t1;
--drop type if exists tp_foo;

create type tp_foo as (i int, x int);

create table t1 of tp_foo;
create table t2 (y text) inherits(t1);

alter type tp_foo add attribute z date cascade;

select * from t2;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this method. Just tested, it will ease my maintenances.